# Send user comment to Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, smarty

I have a member based site with a Facebook-like wall that works the same way as Facebook's does. I would like to give the user an option to send whatever they share on the site to Twitter, FB, and LinkedIn with check boxes, like...

> Type your message here.
>   This is a user message
>   ☐ Check here if you would like to share on Twitter, FB, LinkedIn

---

The user can then decide which boxes to tick and then hit send.

After submission to the site the same message is also posted to whatever sites they ticked.

I don't expect full code but I would like to know what to start with; i.e. what should I google?

Comment: What language(s) is your site written in?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin APIs.

These are the good places to start with:

- Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
- Twitter: http://dev.twitter.com/doc
- Linkedin: http://developer.linkedin.com/community/overview

Hope this was helpful.

Happy coding!

Comment: Nicely answered. Here's a Facebook OAuth class that helped me a lot: https://github.com/Zae/FacebookOAuth.